# SQL truncate clob field

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, truncate, clob

In Oracle I have a query similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    my_field CLOB,
    my_field2 VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
    my_field3 VARCHAR2(5 CHAR),
)
```

and I would like to run this query:

```
select count(*)
from my_table
where my_field = substr('...',4000,1)
```

When I run the query, I get an error:

> 1704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"
>         *Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
>         *Action:   Use a string literal of at most 4000 characters.
>                Longer values may only be entered using bind variables.

Please advice!

Comment: Your example is not comprehensible. please describe it more exactly what is `...`? if I run such a select I get the error message `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB`

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, Oracle is rolling over because you are trying to use a string literal with more than 4000 bytes in it.  One alternative is to use bind variables (as suggested):

```
VARIABLE my_field CLOB;
EXEC :my_field := 'some really long text here longer than 4000 bytes';

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
WHERE my_field = :my_field;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using substr with 4000 character it may be possible that your character set is a multibyte character set due to which memory is more than 4k bytes.
One more approach I can suggest is to use plsql varchar2 variable. It has a limit of 32767.

```
Declare
 my_field varchar2(32767) := <Long text>;
 v_count number;
begin
SELECT COUNT(*) into v_count FROM my_table
WHERE my_field = my_field;

end;
/
```